# Email Content ss

Tags: magento2

I have created an email template in table format and getting that content in below code

```
 $bodyMessage = $transport->getMessage()->getBody()->getPartContent(0);

 $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
 $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
                    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                    ->setTemplateVars($temp_vars)
                    ->setFrom($from)
                    ->addTo($supplier_email)
                    ->getTransport();
 $bodyMessage = $transport->getMessage()->getBody()->getPartContent(0);
```

and i recived email like this

```
=0A=0A=0A=0A=0A=0A=0Aa:visited{color:#1979c3;text-decoration:none}a:hov= er{color:#006bb4;text-decoration:underline}a:active{color:#ff5501;text-d= ecoration:underline}=0A=0A
=0A= =0A=0A=0A
=0A =0A =0A=0A
=0A
=0A =0A =0A =0A <= /tr>=0A
=0A =0A =0A=0A=0A =0A
=0A =20= Thank you=0A =20=

=0A = =0A
```

this is my full code
$mail = new Zend_Mail();

```
        $recipients = array(
            $supplier_name => $supplier_email
        );

        try{
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($temp_vars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($supplier_email)
                ->getTransport();
             $bodyMessage =  $transport->getMessage()->getBodyText();


            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }

        $mail->setBodyHtml($bodyMessage)
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->addTo($recipients)
            ->setFrom($from['name'], $from['email']);

        $attachment = $mail->createAttachment(
            $pdf->render(),
            \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
            \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
            $filename
        );
        $mail->send();
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Please provide proper details

Comment: see update question

Comment: What do you want?  Please explain

Comment: i just upgrade my magento version and i am sending  custom email with html content and pdf attachment but html content showing like the above in my queston

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Magento 2.3.3 please use the following functions to get the content of email from `EmailMessageInterface`

```
/**
 * Return the currently set message body
 *
 * @return MimeMessageInterface
 */
public function getBody(): MimeMessageInterface;

/**
 * Get the string-serialized message body text
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBodyText(): string;

/**
 * Serialize to string
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function toString(): string;
```

You can send email directly by `$transport->sendMessage();` as per your code

Comment: CAN YOU GUIDE THIS IS MY CODE

Comment: @imtiazau please let me know your magento version

Comment: 2.3.3 MAGENTO VERSION

Comment: $bodyMessage = $transport->getMessage()->getBody();

Comment: I REPLACE MY CODE LIKE $bodyMessage = $transport->getMessage()->getBody(); NOW GETTING HTML PROPER BUT Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage Object ( [mimeMessage:Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage:private] => Zend\Mime\Message Object ( [parts:protected] => Array ( [0] => Magento\Framework\Mail\MimePart Object ( [mimePart:Magento\Framework\Mail\MimePart:private] => Zend\Mime\Part Object ( [type] => text/html [encoding] => quoted-printable [id] => [disposition] => inline [filename] => [description] => [charset] => utf-8 [boundary] => [location] => [language] => [content:protected] =>

Comment: AFTER THIS CODE EMAIL CONTENT COMING

Comment: Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessage could not be converted to string in /var/www/au/releases/20191121063758/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mime.php on line 469

Comment: try $bodyMessage = $transport->getMessage()->getBodyText(); or 
$bodyMessage = $transport->getMessage()->toString();  which is mentioned in my answer @imtiazau

Comment: no same email format

Comment: @imtiazau how do you send email? please provide the code

Comment: i edit my question can you check

Comment: vinu sebastain you checked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101310/discussion-between-vinu-sebastian-and-imtiazau).